# npm start not working in ubuntu 20.04 and displaying eslint error

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, npm, eslint, ubuntu-20.04

my react app works fine in my local device. but one I clone it in ubuntu server and try to start it I encounter this eslint Unexpected token.

Does anyone encounter this before?

[image]

Comment: remove your `node_modules` directory and `npm install` again?

Comment: I already tried it earlier. but still getting the same error .

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing the latest version of nodejs in ubuntu server.
btw I'm using node version `v10.19.0` earlier upon encountering this error.
here is the link on how to install latest version of nodejs in ubuntu [How to Install Latest Node.js on Ubuntu](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/)